# Flame in an animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I have been trying to get fire on an "Ark of the Covenant" for months.  It shows that it is there when I run the Timeline playing the frames.  I set everything up in the node editor, exactly as the tutorials say.  But the flame still will not animate.  I don't use GPU. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to the site, what are your simulation settings? Node setup? We need more information than "exactly as the tutorials say". You can edit any new information and screenshots into your question.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more information about your scene. How did you setup your materials? What else have you setup in  terms of render layers? Did you cache the simulation?. Please keep in mind that we know nothing about your scene or your intentions but what you describe in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to "bake your simulation"
It sounds like you are recalculating it every single time you play it
and your computer isnt fast enough to calculate the animation in real time

But if you bake it, it will save the calculations so it wont have to 
re-calculate it all the time.

https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/smoke/baking.html